# Create numpy array from images in different folders

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am a beginner with Python, scikit-learn and numpy. I have a set of folders with images for which I want to do apply different Machine Learning algorithms. I am however struggling to get these images into numpy data that I can use.

These are my prerequisites:

- Each folder name holds the key to what the images are. For example /birds/abc123.jpg and /birds/def456.jpg are both "birds"
- Each image is 100x100px jpg
- I am using Python 2.7
- There are 2800 images in total

This is my code as far as I have gotten:

```
# Standard scientific Python imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import datasets, classifiers and performance metrics
from sklearn import svm, metrics

import numpy as np

import os # Working with files and folders

from PIL import Image # Image processing

rootdir = os.getcwd()
key_array = []
pixel_arr = np.empty((0,10000), int)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
  dir_name = subdir.split("/")[-1]
  if "x" in dir_name:
    key_array.append(dir_name)
    for file in files:
      if ".DS_Store" not in file:
        file = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        im = Image.open(file)
        im_bw = im.convert('1') #Black and white
        new_np = np.array(im_bw2).reshape(1,-1)
        print new_np.shape
        pixel_arr = np.append(pixel_arr, new_np, axis=0)
```

What works in this code is the browsing through the folders, getting the folder names and fetching the correct files/images. What I cannot get to work is to create a numpy array that is 2800,10000 (or maybe the correct would be 10000,2800), i.e. 2800 rows with 10000 values in each.

This solution (that I am not sure if it works) is super slow though and I am quite sure that there must be a solution that is faster and more elegant than this!

**How can I create this 2800x10000 numpy array, preferrably with the index number from the key_array attached?**

Comment: This has nothing to do with scikit-learn. And for the love of all that is holy, upgrade to python 3.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is a part of my ignorance - I am not sure where scikit-learns starts and ends. I will look into upgrading - not really sure why I ended up with 2.7 to be honest.

Comment: Are those input images RGB?

Comment: Yes. The input images are RGB. I (try to) convert them to BW with the im.convert('1').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need all the images at the same time, you can use a generator.

```
def get_images():
  for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('data'):
    dir_name = subdir.split("/")[-1]
    if "x" in dir_name:
      key_array.append(dir_name)
      for file in files:
        if ".DS_Store" not in file:
          file = os.path.join(subdir, file)
          im = Image.open(file)
          im_bw = im.convert('1') #Black and white

          yield np.array(im_bw2).reshape(1,-1)
```

This way you don't hold all the images in memory at the same time, which will probably help you out.

The use the images you would then do:

```
for image in get_images():
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks! It was not exactly what I was looking for but a way to solve my problem.